# Extract specific sections of a text file in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to read in data from a text corpus of science paper abstracts ([available here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/NSF+Research+Award+Abstracts+1990-2003)). I've posted an example file below, where I've read in the data with

```
with open(filePath, "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
for i, x in enumerate(data): print i, x
```

I would like to extract only the category name at line 25 and the text from the Abstract; so in the example below that would be `("Commercial exploitation over the...", "Life Science Biological")`. I cannot assume the category name and abstract will always appear at these specific line numbers. The abstract will always follow 2 lines after `Abstract` and run to the end of the file.

```
0 Title       : CRB: Genetic Diversity of Endangered Populations of Mysticete Whales:

1                Mitochondrial DNA and Historical Demography

2 Type        : Award

3 NSF Org     : DEB 

4 Latest

5 Amendment

6 Date        : August 1,  1991     

7 File        : a9000006

8 

9 Award Number: 9000006

10 Award Instr.: Continuing grant                             

11 Prgm Manager: Scott Collins                           

12        DEB  DIVISION OF ENVIRONMENTAL BIOLOGY       

13        BIO  DIRECT FOR BIOLOGICAL SCIENCES          

14 Start Date  : June 1,  1990       

15 Expires     : November 30,  1992   (Estimated)

16 Expected

17 Total Amt.  : $179720             (Estimated)

18 Investigator: Stephen R. Palumbi   (Principal Investigator current)

19 Sponsor     : U of Hawaii Manoa

20        2530 Dole Street

21        Honolulu, HI  968222225    808/956-7800

22 

23 NSF Program : 1127      SYSTEMATIC & POPULATION BIOLO

24 Fld Applictn: 0000099   Other Applications NEC                  

25               61        Life Science Biological                 

26 Program Ref : 9285,

27 Abstract    :

28                                                                                              

29               Commercial exploitation over the past two hundred years drove                  

30               the great Mysticete whales to near extinction.  Variation in                   

31               the sizes of populations prior to exploitation, minimal                        

32               population size during exploitation and current population                     

33               sizes permit analyses of the effects of differing levels of                    

34               exploitation on species with different biogeographical                         

35               distributions and life-history characteristics.  Dr. Stephen                   

36               Palumbi at the University of Hawaii will study the genetic                     

37               population structure of three whale species in this context,                   

38               the Humpback Whale, the Gray Whale and the Bowhead Whale.  The                 

39               effect of demographic history will be determined by comparing                  

40               the genetic structure of the three species.  Additional studies                

41               will be carried out on the Humpback Whale.  The humpback has a                 

42               world-wide distribution, but the Atlantic and Pacific                          

43               populations of the northern hemisphere appear to be discrete                   

44               populations, as is the population of the southern hemispheric                  

45               oceans.  Each of these oceanic populations may be further                      

46               subdivided into smaller isolates, each with its own migratory                  

47               pattern and somewhat distinct gene pool.  This study will                      

48               provide information on the level of genetic isolation among                    

49               populations and the levels of gene flow and genealogical                       

50               relationships among populations.  This detailed genetic                        

51               information will facilitate international policy decisions                     

52               regarding the conservation and management of these magnificent                 

53               mammals
```

**UPDATE**: the below code works for me, but is there a more efficient way to do this?
    with open(filePath, "r") as f:
        data = f.readlines()

```
  # Find the abstract and category
  abstract = re.compile("Abstract")
  for i, line in enumerate(data):
    if abstract.search(line): break
  # i is the line number of the "Abstract" identifier
  temp = "".join(data[i+1:])
  abstractText = " ".join(re.findall('[A-Za-z]+', temp))
  category = " ".join(re.findall('[A-Za-z]+', data[i-2]))

  return abstractText, category
```

Answer (score 1):

What have you already tried?

If the formatting is consistent you could probably do this with regex.

An example that would catch the abstract might look like:

```
abstract = re.compile(u"Abstract:([\s\w\d]*)", re.MULTILINE)
```

The above code assumes that nothing comes after the abstract's text and that the body of the abstract is always proceeded by "Abstract:"